# display data of json nested objects in html using angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

Newbie to angularjs.trying to display data from json nested object like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXuJo.png)

my html code is

```
<a rel="extranal" data-val="<%rcds%>" ng-repeat="rcds in rcd" class="international" id="<%rcds.id%>">
<span><img ng-src="<% rcds.routes.subroutes %>"/> <% rcds.subroutes[0].xyz%></span>
<div class="departure-time"><% rcds.subroutes[0].abc %></div>
</a>
```

want to display the data subroutes in the ng-repeat based on the condition of legtype in the json.how to do this.

Comment: From what I can tell, you have an array of objects in which you have an array called `routes`, then `depart` and only then you have the `subroutes`. If so, in your code you're trying to access subroutes directly on the root object but it can't find it because it's not there, your code should look something like: `rcds.routes[0].depart[0].subroutes[0].xyz`.  On the other hand, you should be able to nest ng-repeats as well.

Comment: Thanks @Spluf it worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

if you want show your object as JSON the only thing that you need is write `{{rcds | json}}`

Otherwise if you want to navigate your nested object you should do somethings like:

```
<div ng-repeat="rcds in red">
  <div ng-repeat="route in rcds.routes">

    <!-- route element --->

      <div ng-repeat="depart in route.depart">

        <!-- depart element --->

        <div ng-repeat="subroute in route.subroutes">

          <!-- subroute element -->

        </div>

     </div>

  </div>
</div>
```